# PHP MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite::delete all

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to use MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite::delete to delete all records in a collection. The documentation for the filter parameter states that "An empty predicate will match all documents in the collection."

I tried the following:

```
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();
$bulk->delete([]);
$mongo->executeBulkWrite("db.collection", $bulk);`
```

but the following exception is thrown:
MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite::delete() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given.

What would be the correct way to pass what the doc calls "an empty predicate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an empty array as the filter parameter, like this:

```php
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();
$bulk->delete([], ['limit' => 0]);
$mongo->executeBulkWrite("db.collection", $bulk);
```

`limit' => 0` is used to delete all matching documents